# .get with tuples with dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

Say I have a dictionary with tuples as the keys for example

```
dictionary = {('a','b'):1, ('c','d'):2}
```

Is it possible to return `None` if you try to find a value using a key not in the dictionary when using `.get()`?

I've tried

```
dictionary.get('a','c')
```

but this returns an integer and I've tried

```
dictionary.get(['a','c'])
```

and

```
dictionary.get([('a','c')])
```

but both return a type error.

Comment: You made a typo, type: `dictionary.get(('a', 'c'))`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use `('a', 'c')` as the key, you need to write like this:

```
dictionary.get(('a', 'c'))
```

Notice the doubled parentheses, it's necessary like that, to pass a tuple as the key parameter.

If you write `dictionary.get('a', 'c')`,
that means that `'a'` is the key to get,
and `'c'` is the default value to return in case the key doesn't exist.

And `dictionary.get(['a','c'])` cannot work,
because `[...]` is a list, and it's not hashable type.
And in any case `['a', 'c']` is not equal to `('a', 'c')`,
so would not match anyway.